# Read data from networkstream into array

Tags: vb.net

Is there a better way of reading data from a networkstream into an array. The following code works, but it takes a while to receive large amounts of data:

```
Private Function ReadBytes(ByVal NetworkStream As System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream) As Byte()
    Dim Bytes As Byte() = {}
    Dim Index As Integer = 0

    While NetworkStream.DataAvailable = True
        Array.Resize(Bytes, Index + 1)
        Bytes(Index) = NetworkStream.ReadByte()
        Index += 1
    End While

    Return Bytes
End Function
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: See the simple example in [NetworkStream.Read()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read) -- Note that the parts need to agree on a specific encoding. Don't blindly rely on `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` (the example is just an example).

Comment: In addition to Jimi's suggestion, if you use a `List(Of Byte)`, that will resize automatically for you, which should be faster than resizing the array for every byte read.

Comment: Yikes. Are you aware that Array.Resize copies all the data from an old array to a new one just one byte bigger? It doesn't just add another byte on the end. This means that by the time your array reaches 1000 bytes, the first byte has been copied 1000 times, the second byte has been copied 999 times, the third 998 times etc.. Each byte has therefore been copied an average of 500 times and thus, for just 1000 bytes, you've caused *half a million* (half a megabyte's worth of) copy operations. If should perhaps go without saying that you should strive to avoid all this copying.

Comment: Beware, that Andrew's suggestion of using a List(byte) will also cause copying - a list starts out with an internal array of 16 and Array.Resize doubles it every time it gets full. It's nowhere near the insane copy factor that you're doing, but can still lead to huge numbers of copy operations. Presizing a large buffer and developing strategies that don't see you trying to hold all the streamed data in memory in one go are sensible, but as you've told us nothing of the context, we can't really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the docs, this is what I came up with (not tested):

```
Private Sub ReadBytes(ByRef Bytes() As Byte, ByRef NetworkStream As System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream)

 Dim nBr, u As Integer ' nBr = nr. of bytes read 
 u = -1
 Dim L% = 1024 'increase this number to get better performance


 While NetworkStream.DataAvailable

    ReDim Preserve Bytes(u + L)
    nBr = NetworkStream.Read(Bytes, u + 1, L)
    u += nBr
    If nBr < L Then ReDim Preserve Bytes(u)
    
 End While

End Sub
```

Note: Pass large arrays ByRef instead of Function result to avoid unnecessary copying of memory.